# How to return a selection in a laravel 5.5 api using a resource

Tags: php, laravel, api

I want to return a selection from my database whenever a user specifies an id.

I have a laravel 5.5 API with in the api.php the following route.

```
Route::get('companytasks/{id}','TaskController@showOfCompany');
```

In my TaskController i have the following function:

```
public function showOfCompany($id)
{
    // Get tasks with the specifiec company id
    $companytasks = Task::findOrFail($id);
    // Return single task as a resource
    return new TaskResource($companytasks);
}
```

And my resource looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Task extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'TaskCompanyId' => $this->TaskCompanyId,
            'TaskName' => $this->TaskName,
            'TaskDescription' => $this->TaskDescription,
            'Branche' => $this->Branche,
            'Budget' => $this->Budget,
            'TaskFinishDate' => $this->TaskFinishDate,
            'PaydFor' => $this->PaydFor,
            'PublicTask' => $this->PublicTask,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to make a selection from the database where the 'TaskCompanyId' equals the $id.

I can do this with the following line in my controller:

```
$companytasks = Task::where('TaskCompanyId','=',$id)->get();
```

But this does not work for me, I can however add ->first() to it so it only returns the first occurrance but I want all ocurrances to be returned. How do I achieve this?

Comment: If I return $companytasks without using the resource it works perfectly. I just need the resource to specify what fields are bing returned and which are not. How do I make this work with my resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by changing the resource code to:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class Task extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection
        ];
    }
}
```

Making a selection returns a collection instead of an object and therefore needs a ResourceCollection instead of a JsonResource.

Comment: i added collection method and everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'CompanyTaskId' instead of 'TaskCompanyId' in where clause

Comment: Excuse me, I edited this in the question. In my code it is the same. I typed that line by hand but mixed up the name.

Answer (score 0):

Look OK but try with this.

```
$companytasks =  App\Task::where( 'TaskCompanyId' , $id )->get();
```

If you want you can order or paginate

```
$companytasks =  App\Task::where( 'TaskCompanyId' , $id )
     ->orderBy('CompanyTaskId', 'desc')
     ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: This yields the following message: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Printing $id shows the id I provided on the screen so it is initialized.

Comment: Task table has TaskCompanyId ? I know is to simple but sometimes happens to me.

Comment: Yes it has the TaskCompanyId field.

Comment: And you have in your Task model , protected $primaryKey = 'TaskCompanyId'; ?